# Is there a good reason to use a closure instead of a for loop in this case?

Tags: php, closures, php-closures

I'm using Laravel 4; the models in question extend `Eloquent`.

I've got a relationship between two models, `listing` and `photo`. I'm compiling a collection of `listings` that do not have any corresponding `photos`. Eloquent has a handy method for finding records that **DO** have related records:

```
$listings = Listing::has('photos')->get();
```

I'm unaware of the existence of an inverse of the `has` method. *If there is one, please let me know.*

Anyway, this is how I solved the problem:

```
// fetch all the listings, eagerly loading the photos relationship
$listings = Listing::with('photos')->get();

foreach ($listings as $key => $listing)
{
    // if the listing has photos, remove it from the collection
    if (count($listing->photos) != 0)
    {
        unset($listings[$key]);
    }
}
```

This works just fine, but I'm trying to expand my knowledge. Reading the [Laravel documentation on collections](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#collections), there is an example of filtering collections:

```
$users = $users->filter(function($user)
{
    if($user->isAdmin())
    {
        return $user;
    }
});
```

I rewrote my `for` loop using this method:

```
$listings = $listings->filter(function($listing)
{
    // Keep listings with no photos
    if (count($listing->photos) == 0)
    {
        return $listing;
    }
});
```

The resulting `$listings` object is identical both cases. Is there any compelling reason to choose one method over the other, or is it simply a matter of personal preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice between the two is a matter of personal preference.

Some remarks anyway:

If backward compatibility is an issue, then don't use closures. They are a PHP 5.3 language construct. That shouldn't be a problem anymore these days, however.

The only other thing that could play a significant role, is performance. But [for loops are more or less equally fast as closures in PHP](http://www.faieta.net/wp/performance-implications-of-closures-in-php/). And if performance does become an issue, you should change the method altogether and only fetch the right records in the first place.

As for readability: the for loop approach will be easier to understand for unexperienced PHP programmers, while the closure approach is a bit clearer once you understand filtering with closures. Filtering with a closure is more "modern" anyway.